# What is the standard date format used in aviation?

Tags: terminology

As English is the standard language used in aviation and Zulu/UTC time is used as standard too or at least between pilots to calculate flight time and fuel. Is there any standard date format used in the industry like ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is really an industry wide standard for the date format, but at least the ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization) uses the **YYMMDD** date format for flight plans:

> **DOF/** The date of flight departure in a six figure format (YYMMDD, where YY equals the year, MM equals the month and DD equals the day).

<sup>([FAA on ICAO flight plans](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/fs_html/appendix_a.html))</sup>

Other flight plans may use different formats however. See e.g. the following example of a LIDO flight plan (Lufthansa Systems format):

[image: LIDO flight plan]
<sup>(image source: [SimBrief.com](https://www.simbrief.com/system/guide.php?ofpformat=lido2#ofpsample))</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Depends a bit on where the date is used.

For flightplans, the Date Of Flight (DOF) should be inserted in item 18 in the format YYMMDD (for example **200816** for the 16th of August 2020).

In a NOTAM, a format similar to the DOF flightplan format is used, but usually with the addition of four digits to indicate the time (HHMM):

C0424/20 NOTAMN Q) EKDK/QWGLW/IV/M /AW/000/060/5601N00901E005 A) EKAB B) **2008061000** C) **2008162000** D) DAILY 1000-2000 E) INTENSIVE GLIDER FLYING WILL TAKE PLACE AROUND ARNBORG AIRFIELD EKAB PSN 560043N0090045E. F) SFC G) 6000FT AMSL

As for aeronautical publications:

> 4.2.3        Each  AIP  shall  be  dated.  In  the  case  of  AIP  issued  in  loose-leaf  form,  each  page  shall  be  dated.  The  date,  consisting of the day, month (by name) and year, shall be the publication date or the effective date of the information.

*ICAO Annex 15*

This typically means **16 AUG 20**, **16 AUG 2020** or **16 AUGUST 2020**.